# Is there a way to listen for metadata changes in Google Cloud Storage in a web client?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I'd like to set a listener ala a Firestore document listener to automatically trigger a callback when the metadata changes. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [Cloud Storage events for Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events):

> Cloud Storage supports these events:
>
> `onArchive`: Only sent when a bucket has enabled object versioning. This event indicates that the live version of an object has become an archived version, either because it was archived or because it was overwritten by the upload of an object of the same name.
>
> `onDelete`: Sent when an object has been permanently deleted. This includes objects that are overwritten or are deleted as part of the bucket's lifecycle configuration. For buckets with object versioning enabled, this is not sent when an object is archived (see onArchive), even if archival occurs via the `storage.objects.delete` method.
>
> `onFinalize`: Sent when a new object (or a new generation of an existing object) is successfully created in the bucket. This includes copying or rewriting an existing object. A failed upload does not trigger this event.
>
> `onMetadataUpdate`: Sent when the metadata of an existing object changes.

So it looks like `onMetadataUpdate` should work, although I admit I never used that trigger myself.

Comment: Are these only possible from cloud functions or is there a way to do this in a web client? Sorry needed to clarify my question.

Comment: Oh, sorry... I blindly assumed this was for Cloud Functions. There is no way to get callbacks to a web client for changes to Cloud Storage that I know of. The common approach for that would be to write the metadata to Firebase's [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web_value_events) or [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) (for example: from a Cloud Function), and then listen for those changes in the web client.

Comment: Hey @Andrew. Anything else needed here?

Comment: no that makes sense, if you don't know a way to get changes to the web client that is as close to a definitive source I can think of